# How to hide the clock icon in Visual Studio search?

Tags: visual-studio-code

My search feature on VS Code looks like this. I don't understand why the clock icon appears. Is it a bug or a feature? When the clock appears, I just close VS Code and open it again. Can I hide the clock forever?

[image: screen shot]

Comment: It could mean a few things, I have seen a clock in other locations and it was an indicator that something was taking a long time, and another time that had something to do with the editors history, oh I remember, I think its the icon thats also used for clearing the editors history. Anyway, if you just hover over it the hover widget will display a message that communicates what the icon is there for.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply hide the badge. Right click -> Hide Badge

[image]